# How to implement a transparency or opacity control bar in HTML

Tags: android, overlay, opacity, transparent-control

I have two maps which are overlayed on each other. Now I want to add opacity control for them . But I don't know how to do that . Kindly suggest. I am overlaying maps in HTMl which is added in webview. 
Thanks 
Astha